quarto file for beamer, compilation failed- no matching packages LaTeX Error: File `beamer.cls' not found
I am running the example on https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/#learning-more in Rstudio
---

title: "Habits"
author: "John Doe"
format: revealjs
-

## Getting up

- Turn off alarm
- Get out of bed

## Going to sleep

- Get in bed
- Count sheep


Copy and paste, it shows the following:

==\> quarto preview learning1.qmd --to beamer --no-watch-inputs --no-browse

pandoc
to: beamer
output-file: learning1.tex
standalone: true
pdf-engine: xelatex
variables:
graphics: true
tables: true
default-image-extension: pdf

metadata
block-headings: true
title: Habits
author: John Doe

running xelatex - 1
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=xelatex)
restricted \\write18 enabled.
entering extended mode

updating tlmgr

updating existing packages
finding package for beamer.cls

compilation failed- no matching packages
LaTeX Error: File \`beamer.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or \<RETURN\> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
\<read \*\>

l.8 \\usepackage
{pgfpages}^^M

see learning1.log for more information.

I tried reinstall tinytex and update, but it doesnot work. Thanks for the help in advance. How to make beamer work in .qmd

Your tinytex seems to use a texlive from 2022, this will cause problems as the current texlive mirrors provide texlive2024. You could try with an historic mirror, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/580117/36296 (use 2022 instead of 2019) or install a current texlive.

... not your fault, but the fault of quartos unsuitable default settings, but I highly recommend not using xelatex with beamer. This can make text in notes disappear, cause wrong overlay colours etc.)

Thanks very much for the suggestion, very helpful, I am trying the way here to fix the texlive version problem. Thanks for the suggestion on xelatex again, but how to change the compiler here, I cannot see a button on render for changing latex compiler.

See https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/pdf-engine.html#alternate-pdf-engines how to change the engine in the document. If you want a fast compilation, I would use pdflatex. If you need special fonts etc., I would suggest lualatex.

Thanks a lot, it works!!! I change the pdf-engine to pdflatex and update the tinytex through the install_tinytex() and it works! Very helpful! (btw, the beamer runs very slow)
